# Filter json response in array of dictionary inside dictionary Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsdictionary, jsonresponse

I am getting a response of NSDictionary list of products as

```
 {
"products": {
    "title": "Chair",
    "regular_price": "2.22",
    "dimensions": {
        "width": "",
        "height": "",
        "length": ""
    },
    "attributes": [{
        "options": ["11\/30\/2016"],
        "name": "Arrival Date"
    }, {
        "options": ["Black"],
        "name": "Color"
    }],
    "categories": ["28"]
}
```

}.....

Using NSPredicate I could filter the products containing value "Chair" using

```
let namepredicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == Chair")
           self.filteredProducts = (self.product).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(namepredicate)
```

But How can I filter "Color", "Black" which inside the attributes and "Black" is inside another array(Swift)?

Comment: There's no reason to be using `NSArray` or `NSPredicate` for something like this. Use Swift's native `Array` and `filter`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Can you provide an example for filtering above response?

Comment: Sure, I'll write up a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, rename `self.product` to `self.products`. It's an array of multiple products, name it accordingly.

You can replace the existing `NSPredicate` mess with just:

```
self.filteredProducts = self.products.filter{ $0["title"] == "Chair" }
```

And you can filter by Color like so:

```
self.filteredProducts = self.products.filter{ product in
    return product["attributes"]?.contains{ attribute in
        return attribute["name"] == "Color" &&
               attribute["options"]?.contains("Black") ?? false
    } ?? false
}
```

Comment: @DineshKumar I don't follow... what?

Comment: @ AlexanderMomchilov, Basically, I need to filter the array based on color which is inside attributes array as shown in the code shared in original question. Filter by title may work but I need to filter based on color which is not a direct key in dictionary.

Comment: Oh I missed that last sentence. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DineshKumar You would have a much much easier time working with this data structure if you properly parsed it into structs